# How Do I Move Stuff From My Phone's Memory To An SD Card?

Tags: lumia-520, storage, sd-card

How do I move my music, pictures and apps et cetera from my phone's memory over to an SD card which I had to buy?  I fitted the SD card into the phone (Nokia Lumia 520 - running Windows 8.1) only to be repeatedly told thereon that I still need space and I should move some stuff over to the SD card but I'm at a loss as to how that's done. Can you help please?

Comment: I've not got a phone with an SD card slot to hand, but believe the Storage Sense app might be able to do this for you

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running Windows Phone 8.1, you can use the Storage Sense app to move apps, photos, videos, etc from the phone's memory to the SD card...

1. In the App list, tap Storage Sense Storage Sense Tile > Phone > Apps + games.
2. To move one app, tap the app, and then tap Move to SD. To move more than one, tap Select Select icon, select the check box next to each one you want to move, and then tap Move.
3. To move apps back to the phone, in Storage Sense, go to SD card > Apps + games.

Taken from [the official Windows Phone how-to website](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/phones-and-hardware/use-an-sd-card-to-add-space)